# Webpack: How to add a folder of JS files to the bundler

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a react application that I'm developing and I'm not too familiar with webpack.  I've implemented a bootstrap theme with some custom JavaScript and it works fine when I link all the scripts manually in my `index.html` body.

The hack method is quite messy and gives me less control later when it comes to minifying all the scripts.

All my scripts are in a single folder called `vendor` located in `src`. How can I bundle all the files in the `vendor` folder with the other stuff that is bundled with webpack?

Here's my webpack file for reference:

```
const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")
const path = require('path')
const loaders = require('./webpack.loaders')

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    resolve: {
        root: [ path.resolve(__dirname, "src")],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
    entry: "./js/client.js",
    module: {
        loaders: loaders.concat([
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
                    plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy']
                }
            }
        ])
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/src/",
        filename: "client.min.js"
    },
    plugins:
        debug ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
            new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false })
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show how you can import all files within your folder. We're going to use the `require` syntax despite the `import` is more common for now. (just not sure that it's possible via `import`, maybe somebody can clarify).

So:

```
const req = require.context('./src/vendor/', true, /.js$/);
req.keys().forEach((filename) => req(filename));
```

It will require all your JS files from './src/vendor/'.

I think then everything is clear if you are familiar with the `require` syntax. If not, make sure that your JS files have something like the following:

```
module.exports = function theme() {
  // do some stuff
  return 'some stuff';
}
```

And you might want to use it like this:

```
const req = require.context('./src/vendor/', true, /.js$/);
req.keys().forEach((filename) => {
  const theme = req(filename);
  theme();
});
```